# Find the longest path of 'A's in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, char

Hello and any help is greatly appreciated!

I need to create a program that goes through a char array that it reads in from a file. The program then needs to use recursion to find the longest consecutive path of 'A's that are adjacent (not diagonal) to the current 'A'. It can only count each 'A' once, so it can't go backwards once it reaches the end of the path. The example char array I am working with is:

```
8 13
EAADDOAN
ATAFAWOB
ADAAAAIA
AWUYAAAA
ZAWAADDX
AAAAAAAZ
IMBAQJAA
AIAINOAK
AZVAJAAQ
VPNKAAAJ
TAAAWKAW
AAAAHRAV
ETEMAALA

Length of the longest A path is 23
```

The 8 signifies the columns and the 13 is the rows of the array. I have set up another boolean array to keep track if an 'A' has already been counted or not. Below is the method that iterates through each position and calls the recursive function (looks kinda weird, first time posting on here):

```
public int findLongestPathLength() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int i, j, x, y;
int numOfAs = 0;
int longestPath = 0;

// Create boolean array for checking if an 'A' has been counted or not
alreadyCounted = new boolean[numOfArrays][arrLength];

// Initialize all values in alreadyCounted array to false
for(i = 0; i < numOfArrays; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < arrLength; j++ ) {
        alreadyCounted[i][j] = false;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < numOfArrays; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < arrLength; j++ ) {
        if(map[i][j] == 'A') {
            alreadyCounted[i][j] = true;
            numOfAs = findPathLengthRecursive(i, j) + 1;

/* If this iteration of finding the longest path of 'A's is the longest
    so far, replace the longestPath value with this number of A's */
if(numOfAs > longestPath)
    longestPath = numOfAs;

// Initialize all values in alreadyCounted array back to false
    for(x = 0; x < numOfArrays - 1; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < arrLength - 1; y++ ) {
            alreadyCounted[x][y] = false;
        }
    }

// Reset currentLength in findPathLengthRecursive back to 0
    currentLength = 0;

}               
}
}

    return longestPath;
}
```

The recursive method I created is:
    public int findPathLengthRecursive(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    // To check if there is an 'A' to any of the sides of the current cell
    boolean left = true, right = true, up = true, down = true;

    /* Base case (when recursion should stop) is when there is no 'A's left to count in the path */ 
    if(j == 0 || (j > 0 && (map[i][j - 1] != 'A' || alreadyCounted[i][j - 1]))){
        left = false;
    }

    if(j == arrLength - 1 || (j < arrLength - 1 && (map[i][j + 1] != 'A' || alreadyCounted[i][j + 1]))) {
        right = false;
    }

    if(i == numOfArrays - 1 || (i < numOfArrays - 1 && (map[i + 1][j] != 'A' || alreadyCounted[i + 1][j]))) {
        down = false;
    }
    if(i == 0 || (i > 0 && (map[i - 1][j] != 'A' || alreadyCounted[i - 1][j]))) {
        up = false;
    }

    // If there is no valid 'A's around then return currentLength
    if(!left && !right && !down && !up) {
        return currentLength;
    } else {
        if(down && left && up && right) {
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1)), findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j)), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1));
        }   
        else if(left && up && right) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j)), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1));
        }
        else if(up && right && down) {
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1)), findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j));
        }
        else if(right && down && left) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j)), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1));
        }
        else if(down && left && up) {
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1)), findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j));
        }
        else if(left && right) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1));

        } 
        else if(up && down) {
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j), findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j)); 
        }
        else if(left && up) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j));
        } 
        else if(left && down) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j));
        } 
        else if(right && up) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j));
        }
        else if(right && down) {
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            currentLength += Math.max(findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1), findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j));
        } 
        else if(left) {
            currentLength++;
            alreadyCounted[i][j - 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1); 
        }
        else if(up) {
            currentLength++;
            alreadyCounted[i - 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j); 
        }
        else if(right) {
            currentLength++;
            alreadyCounted[i][j + 1] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1); 
        }
        else if(down) {
            currentLength++;
            alreadyCounted[i + 1][j] = true; // Show that this 'A' has already been counted
            findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j); 
        }

    }
    return currentLength;

}
```

No matter what I try It seems to just be returning random numbers that aren't close to the 23 I'm looking for.

This is the output from the recursive method when it is called from the first method.

136
70
1
3
70
58
1
56
70
36
37
1
3
60
53
69
85
66
69
85
66
54
43
63
51
49
79
84
109
142
2
1
139
2
1
87
116
119
118
132
3
4
3
100
5
4
2
1
166
2
1
1
166

Any help would be really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution already, but I think it doesn't reset the visited state properly, which can make it miss significant path options (the previous sum vs. max issue was apparently fixed in the meantime).

If you want to learn something and fix and improve your own, I'd recommend to move all logic to the start of the recursive function:

- Is the position under investigation within the bounds?
- Is it an 'A'?
- Was it not counted already?

If any condition is false, just exit early by returning 0.

This allows you to just mark the position as counted after the checks, then call the method recursively for all directions without extensive checks there and return the maximum + 1. You can call for invalid positions, as that's checked inside the recursive function. Don't forget to use the result of the recursive call.

Not repeating the checks will avoid copy-paste errors and extra loops or the need for direction arrays.

Don't forget to unmark when leaving the recursive function.

**Edit**: Pseudocode to better illustrate the simplification (you'll need to replace the comments and "..." with the corresponding code):

```
 public int findPathLengthRecursive(int i, int j) {
   if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= ... ) {
     return 0;
   }

   // Check here that there is an A at the position, otherwise return 0

   // Mark the current position as visited here

   int result = 1 + Math.max(
       Math.max(
          findPathLengthRecursive(i - 1, j),
          findPathLengthRecursive(i + 1, j)),
       Math.max(
          findPathLengthRecursive(i, j - 1),
          findPathLengthRecursive(i, j + 1)));

   // Remove the mark for the current position here

   return result;
 }
```

Basically

1. Checking everything at the beginning of the recursive function avoids the need for multiple (error prone) checks where you make the recursive call
2. The mark needs to be removed when returning from the recursion to check for alternatives
3. the return values from the recursion need to be taken into account properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, could you possibly show me an example? Thank you for your help

Comment: I have expanded the answer to include a code sceleton

Answer (score 0):

```
char [][]mat;

boolean visit[][];

int rowSize , columnSize;

int dx[] = {-1 , 0  ,  0 , +1};
int dy[] = { 0 , +1 , -1 ,  0};

int rec(int row , int col){

    visit[row][col] = true;

    int ret = 0;

    for(int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; ++k){
        int nr = row+dx[k];
        int nc = col+dy[k];

        if(nr < 0 || nr >= rowSize || nc < 0 || nc >= columnSize || visit[nr][nc] && mat[nr][nc] != 'A'){   
            continue;       
        }
        ret += 1 + rec(nr , nc);
    }

    return ret;

}


void main(){
    //todo input the matris and rowSize , columnSize

    //todo make all item of visit by 0;

    int mx = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rowSize; ++i){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < columnSize; ++j){
            int cur = rec(i ,j);
            mx = mx > cur ? mx : cur;
        }
    }

    //mx is answer

}
```

Comment: What does the dx [] and dy[] arrays do? Why do they have that set of numbers in them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The dx and dy arrays basically map a direction (up, down etc..) encoded as numer in the range from 0 to 4 to the corresponding relative x and y movement. This allows to easily loop over all possible directions.